# How to implement a Viewgroup with child views stacked like a deck of cards?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I wanted to implement a UI similar to the Android L's home screen, where if we tap to see the recent applications, it shows the recent applications in a stacked view like a deck of cards .

Is it possible to figure out from android source code , how they have achieved it?
And btw android's google chrome app also has this stacked views when showing multiple tabs?

Comment: the exact algorithm shouldn't be hard,  all you need is to override onLayout and/or onMeasure methodes

Comment: @pskink Is it possible for me to reuse that algorithm from android L's home screen UI?

Comment: probably yes,  i don't think they're using L specific API for that

Comment: @user3665376 Have you found the solution for this? if yes, I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the movement of the panels would work.

However, the stacked panels are most likely a FrameLayout with child ViewGroups (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout) or a Fragment.

The distance illusion would then be demonstrated by utilizing the elevation attribute

ex: `elevation: 10dp`.

---

Furthermore, the Chrome browser example would most likely have child Fragments so each browser tab is its own instance.